# Add custom operators to BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF types

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` to create strong types from primitives.

However, whereas previously I could just increment/decrement the primitive, now there is no available operator.

Is it possible to overload the increment or decrement operator from outside of the `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` source code, so the compiler joins the two together?

Comment: Look like it ought to be `D& operator++(D& o) {++o.t; return o;}`?

Comment: Works for me live - https://godbolt.org/z/n336ss9nY - please post a [mcve]  You might also want to include the version(s) of Boost you are using.

Comment: @MooingDuck Thank you, can you post as an answer and i'll accept.